# Laravel: store file in sub-directory of strorage path

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage, directory-structure

I have the following folder-structure:

```
-storage 
  -app
    -orders
      -cat1
      -cat2
```

Within either the `cat1` or the `cat2` folder (depending on user input) I want to create another folder and put a xml file in there.
This is how I tried to create the directory within the `cat1`-folder and put the xml file in there:

```
$uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
$id = $uuid->toString();
$path = '/orders/cat1/'.$id;
Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
Storage::put($id.'test.xml', $xml);
```

**What happens:**
The folder ($id as name) gets created in the right place:

```
-storage
  -app
    -orders
      -cat1
        -123456789
      -cat2
```

But the xml will be stored in another folder here:

```
-storage
  -app 
    -123456789   // xml gets stored in another
       -test.xml // folder within app-folder
    -orders
       -cat1
          -123456789 // where the xml should be placed
       -cat2
```

I just can seem to find a way to put the xml in the directory I've just created ._.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Storage::put` starts from `app` folder.

Use this code:

```
Storage::put($path . '/test.xml', $xml);
```

Comment: of Storage::disk('disk')->put($path . '/test.xml', $xml);
if you want/defined another disk

Answer (score 2):

You could try to store it like this:

```
Storage::put($path . '/test.xml', $xml);
```